# Swift 4 DispatchGroup repeating NSTimer calls until condition is met

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, core-bluetooth

The bluetooth library doesn't have call backs so when I write a message there is no callback to say i've received the correct response.

So i'm currently using Dispatch group to make syncronous calls.

Is this the best method for doing the following?

I essentially want the following to happen.
Write a command and set a timer of say 1s.
Now every 0.1s I want to call a function until i've received the correct response.
If i've received the right response I will continue calling the next write command and checking for the write response.

Comment: you sure what you want is not in [cbcentralmanagerdelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate) or [cbperipheraldelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate)

Comment: Are you writing `.withResponse`?

Comment: Yes I am. I get that you can set the delagates once the didUpdateValue and didWrite functions are updated but I want a way to be able to confirm that I’ve written successfully and received a response. Essentially confirming two delegates

Comment: https://github.com/LGBluetooth/LGBluetooth ?

Comment: Polling is rarely the best solution. In this case I would suggest that you register the expected response. When you get a response from the peripheral you can check whether it is what was expected or not and then invoke an appropriate delegate method or callback closure indicating success or error.

Comment: That's a good point @Paulw11, do you happen to know of any examples for a callback closure?

Comment: You can find plenty of examples on using closures.  You can start with the chapter in the Swift Book from Apple.  For your needs I would create a struct that defined the operation, the expected result and that holds a reference to the callback closure.  You can then submit these to a "queue" (An array, not a GCD queue) that your Bluetooth process uses to determine what to do next and what to do with a response

Comment: Awesome thanks, i'll give it a go. Seems a lot more sound than what I originally had.